# Skipping over array elements of certain types

Tags: string, python-2.7, floating-point

I have a csv file that gets read into my code where arrays are generated out of each row of the file. I want to ignore all the array elements with letters in them and only worry about changing the elements containing numbers into floats. How can I change code like this:

```
myValues = []
data = open(text_file,"r")
for line in data.readlines()[1:]:
    myValues.append([float(f) for f in line.strip('\n').strip('\r').split(',')])
```

so that the last line knows to only try converting numbers into floats, and to skip the letters entirely?

Put another way, given this list,

```
list = ['2','z','y','3','4']
```

what command should be given so the code knows not to try converting letters into floats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use try: except:

```
for i in list:
    try:
        myVal.append(float(i))
    except:
        pass
```